# Error while converting text to speech in python

Tags: python-3.x, gtts

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os

Text= "hello world" 
Lang= "en"
     SPEECH=gTTS(Text,Lang,slow=False)
SPEECH.save("hello.mp3")
os.system("start hello.mp3)
```

It raise an error

> failed to connect  Probable cause: Unknown

Please guide how to resolve it

Comment: `failed to connect` - Are you connected to internet while doing this?

Comment: No when I initially ran the code I was not connected
after error I connected my desktop with internet

Comment: gTTS requires online API to perform TTS transformation. Connecting to internet should resolve that.

Comment: It is still raising same error even if I am connected to internet